# For loop iterator type not the same as type I am trying to access

Tags: java, list, loops, ibeacon-android, estimote

I am trying to iterate through a for loop and set elements of an list based on the iteration it is at, but the iteration type is not the same type as the list I want to access

```
private List<Double> myBeaconDistances = new ArrayList<>();

private List getBeaconDistances(List<Beacon> beacons){
    for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
        double distance = Utils.computeAccuracy(beacon);
        this.myBeaconDistances.set(beacon, distance);

    }

    return myBeaconDistances;
}
```

The error displayed is that beacon is not the correct type, it is supposed to be an integer, but Beacons are not integers. Does anyone know a way to add another iterator or set beacon to an integer temporarily?

```
distance = Utils.commputeAccuracy(beacon) will return an double.
```

Btw Beacons are just some object I made, but they consists of UUID, major, and minor numbers. This might be irrelevant, but just incase you wanted to know. Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to store key-value pairs consisting of a beacon and a distance, such that given a beacon you can lookup a distance?  If so you need a `Map<Beacon,Integer>`, not a `List`.  Also if that is the case, `Beacon` must correctly implement `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: Just a Little bit nitpicking: it really helps to try to understand the error message the compiler is giving you! Jim Garrison is right, btw.

Comment: @JimGarrison yes that is what I am trying to do, thank you I will implement that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `Map` instead of a `List`:

```
private Map<Beacon,Double> myBeaconDistances = new HashMap<>();

private Map<Beacon,Double> getBeaconDistances(List<Beacon> beacons){
    for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
        double distance = Utils.computeAccuracy(beacon);
        this.myBeaconDistances.put(beacon, distance);

    }

    return myBeaconDistances;
}
```

When you do this you must also implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in `Beacon` based on whatever "equality" means, and they must be consistent with each other.  Read the Javadoc for the `Map` interface.

In your case it is likely that "equals" has to consider the UUID and major/minor version numbers.  The following assumes major/minor are primitive types, and that UUID cannot be null.  Add extra checking or substitute `equals()` for `==` as appropriate:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if (this == other) return true;
    if (other == null || !this.isAssignableFrom(other)) return false;
    Beacon b = (Beacon) other;
    return this.uuid.equals(b.uuid) && this.major == b.major && this.minor == b.minor;
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{ 
    return 2047*this.major + this.minor + this.uuid.hashCode();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're calling set on an ArrayList.  The first argument should be an int, not a type Beacon.

In `this.myBeaconDistances.set(beacon, distance);`

See 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)